# MySQL syntax error unexpected '-'

Tags: mysql

I just noticed an error in my MySQL logs:

> syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting FTS_TEXT or FTS_TERM or
>   FTS_NUMB or '('

As far as I can tell this doesn't relate to a query and doesn't have a timestamp on it (all other entries in the log do). Has anyone seen this before? Does it relate to a configuration error or data corruption? Is it something malicious?

Comment: Looks like typical mysql error response to client, related to query to the InnoDB table with full text search option, but it's logged and this is strange (fact that's it is logged, not the error). Can you please copy entire line from log and few more lines before and after this message?

Comment: The previous lines are when the server started up (4 days before this message). What I pasted above is the entire line, which is weird because errors are normally time stamped.

Comment: Previous log entries: http://pastebin.com/McMu0w1j

Comment: It's a bug, definitely